# Making assistive touch using flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile, dart

I want to achieve assistive touch as apple provides in Flutter. Any help with links and docs would be appreciated. Here I am attaching sample -

[image]

And it should open same as iOS.

[image]

Comment: You mean you want something like that in your app?

Comment: Yes, I want to achieve the same in app and click on this will open actions with the same animation as it opens in iOS.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Use `GestureDetector` with `Container`. You try and if stuck at some point share the code here, we will help.

Comment: Dear just google "`GestureDetector` flutter" in google, you will lot of reference from those try to takle with that widget and then search peace by peace, instead someone else tell you what to do, that way you will get much knowledge.

Comment: Hello, I wanted to do the same thing but i want my app to create a bubble and keep it floating over all the applications. Like screen recorder applications. Can someone help?

Comment: @AtharvaKadlag did you get any solution? Im looking for same

Comment: @LMKIND nope i couldnt find anything

Comment: Gesture detector won't help over here. What we need is something similar to SystemAlertWindow but more customisable. It is not very customisable as such and hence, doesn't make for a very good alternative.